# How does Twitter "mention" spam actually work?

Tags: twitter, spam-prevention

I'm just curious to know what the programming mechanics behind it are - more & more, when I tweet or RT something, I get a "mentioned you" spam back almost instantly.

This account is not following me, so what technique are they using to detect that my account has just tweeted?

Comment: Your mentions also won't arrive with people who aren't following when you are protected, double edged sword

Comment: @Richard Except then you have to approve follows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They use the [Streaming API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/streams/public) in order to get a real-time feed of all Tweets containing certain words, expressions or hashtags (it's like a real-time search), then they can retweet or reply if they want to. If you don't want unauthorized people to see your Tweets, then change your account to Protected in your [Account settings](https://twitter.com/settings/account); that will only allow people who follow you (and who you accepted - they can't directly follow you, only send you a follow request) to see your tweets - they won't appear in any public search or in the streaming API.